Natural Cubic Spline interloping 4 points
I have the question "Find the "natural" cubic spline, the one satisfying

$s''(x_{0})=s''(x_{n})=0$ that passes through
$$
(x_{i},y_{i})= (0,0), (1,2),(2,1) \text{ and } (3,0 )
$$
<\strike>
For convenience express the spline in the form
$$
s(x)_{[x_{i},x_{i+1}]}= a_{i}+b_{i}(x-x_{i})+c_{i}(x-x_{i})^2+d_{i}(x-x_{i})^3
$$ " 
And so far I have: 

We first define our $h_{i}=x_{i+1}-x_{i}$ so we have
$$
h_{0}= 1-0=1, h_{1}=2-1=1, h_{2}=3-2=1
$$
So we have all $h_{i}=1$
Now we find the difference quotient for each segment
$$
b_{i}=\frac{y_{i+1}-y_{i}}{h_{i}}
$$
$$
\Rightarrow b_{0}= \frac{2-0}{1}= 2, b_{1}= \frac{1-2}{1}=-1, b_{2}=\frac{0-1}{1}=-1
$$
Now we want to set up a sytem to find our $z_{i}=s''(x_{i})$ where we have $z_{0}=z_{3}=0$
We begin to find $z_{1}$ and $z_{2}$ from the natural spline equations
which are
$$
6(b_{i}-b_{i-1})= h_{i-1}z_{i-1}+ 2(h_{i-1}+h_{i})z_{i}+ h_{i}z_{i+1}
$$
So considering $z_{0}=0$ and $z_{3}=0$ we have the following equations
$$
6(b_{1}-b_{0})=h_{0}z_{0}+ 2(h_{0}+h_{1})z_{1}+ h_{1}z_{2}= 2(h_{0}+h_{1})z_{1}+h_{1}z_{2} 
$$
$$
6(b_{2}-b_{1})=h_{1}z_{1}+2(h_{1}+h_{2})z_{2}+ h_{2}z_{3}= h_{1}z_{1}+2(h_{1}+h_{2})z_{2}
$$
Now we plug in and solve the system
$$
6(-1-(2))=2(1+1)z_{1}+ 1z_{2}\Rightarrow 6(-3)= 4z_{1}+ z_{2}= -18=4z_{1}+z_{2}
$$
$$
6(-1-(-1))=1(z_{1})+2(1+1)z_{2}\Rightarrow 0=z_{1}+ 4z_{2}
$$
Now we solve the system
$$
z_{1}=-4z_{2}\Rightarrow -18=4(-4z_{2})+z_{2}\Rightarrow -18= -16z_{2}+z_{2}\Rightarrow z_{2}= \frac{18}{15}
$$
plugging back in
$$
z_{1}=-4\left( \frac{18}{15} \right)\Rightarrow z_{1}= -\frac{72}{15}\Rightarrow z_{1}= -\frac{24}{5}
$$
Now we want to find our spline functions
we let $t_{i}=x_{i}$ for $i=0,1,2,3$ and have
$$
S''(x)= \frac{x_{i}-x}{h_{i}}z_{i-1}+ \frac{x-x_{i-1}}{h_{i}}z_{i}
$$
Integrating this twice we obtain
$$
S(x)= \frac{(x_{i}-x)^3}{6h_{i}}z_{i-1}+ \frac{(x-x_{i-1})^3}{6h_{i}}z_{i}+ \alpha_{i}(x-x_{i-1})+\beta_{i}(x_{i}-x)
$$

But I don't know how to proceed from here to find the coefficients a_i, b_i or to change the spline equation into the desired form.

You need to compute 12 coefficients in total (3 cubic polynomials, one in each subinterval). Consider now:

6 equations forcing the spline to actually interpolate the data
2 equations to force continuous first derivative at x = 1 and x = 2
2 equations to force continuous second derivative at x = 1 and x = 2
2 equations setting zero second derivative at x = 0 and x = 3

Solving this linear system you'll get all the coefficients.
